# Change Selected cell in Grouped Table View

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have create a Static Cells Table view with Grouped style
[image]

As you can see from the image above my problem is the accessory and opaque that will be seen when I click to any of the cell which does not corresponds to the white background.Can someone help me fix this problem?

Here's my code that achieves the rounded corners of the section.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    }



    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        if (cell.respondsToSelector(Selector("tintColor"))){

            if (tableView == self.tableView) {

                let cornerRadius : CGFloat = 12.0
                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
                let layer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
                let pathRef:CGMutablePathRef = CGPathCreateMutable()
                let bounds: CGRect = CGRectInset(cell.bounds, 25, 0)
                var addLine: Bool = false

                if (indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.row == tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(indexPath.section)-1) {
                    CGPathAddRoundedRect(pathRef, nil, bounds, cornerRadius, cornerRadius)
                } else if (indexPath.row == 0) {
                    CGPathMoveToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds))
                    CGPathAddArcToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds), CGRectGetMidX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds), cornerRadius)
                    CGPathAddArcToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds), CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMidY(bounds), cornerRadius)
                    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds))
                    addLine = true

                } else if (indexPath.row == tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(indexPath.section)-1) {
                    CGPathMoveToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds))
                    CGPathAddArcToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds), CGRectGetMidX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds), cornerRadius)
                    CGPathAddArcToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds), CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMidY(bounds), cornerRadius)
                    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds))

                } else {
                    CGPathAddRect(pathRef, nil, bounds)
                    addLine = true

                }

                layer.path = pathRef
                layer.fillColor = UIColor(red: 255/255.0, green: 255/255.0, blue: 255/255.0, alpha: 0.8).CGColor

                if (addLine == true) {
                    let lineLayer: CALayer = CALayer()
                    let lineHeight: CGFloat = (1.0 / UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)
                    lineLayer.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(bounds)+10, bounds.size.height-lineHeight, bounds.size.width-10, lineHeight)
                    lineLayer.backgroundColor = tableView.separatorColor!.CGColor
                    layer.addSublayer(lineLayer)
                }

                let testView: UIView = UIView(frame: bounds)
                testView.layer.insertSublayer(layer, atIndex: 0)
                testView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
                cell.backgroundView = testView
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why you are doing this much logic to design your cells rather than using story board customisation ?

Comment: Actually that code is for each group rounded corners only.. note not table cells.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to change the selected color of the cell, you can do this:

Objective-C:

```
UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
bgColorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[cell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];
```

Swift:

```
var bgColorView = UIView()
bgColorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
cell.selectedBackgroundView = bgColorView
```

For cell corner rounds:

```
cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
cell.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Comment: actully what i want is just like ipad general settings.Thats the reason why in the image i have posted contains Disclosure Indicator.

Answer (score 0):

Going with your implementation, there is also a `selectedBackgroundView` property for `UITableViewCell`, so you could just add this code at the end of the method.

I just created another view with another shapeLayer with the copy of the path you've created, changing the fillColor to indicate selection.

```
        let selectedLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        selectedLayer.path = CGPathCreateCopy(pathRef)
        selectedLayer.fillColor = UIColor(white: 0.75, alpha: 0.8).CGColor
        let selectedView = UIView(frame: bounds)
        selectedView.layer.insertSublayer(selectedLayer, atIndex: 0)
        selectedView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectedView
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. it works but the how can i fix the disclosure indicator?I would really mark your answer as correct if you could help me about the indicator.

Comment: Oh, there's probably no non-hacky way to change the frame of the default disclosure indicator. You could create your own accessory view that looks like a disclosure indicator and set it to the cell so you could provide a custom frame for it.

Answer (score 0):

Hello lopez all you have to do is to diable selection style on the UITableViewCell

**1) iOS** 

`cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
or 
[cell setAlpha:0.5]`;

**2 Swift**
another approach may be

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
carTableView?.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
```

}

Happy Programming

Comment: Sorry but I dont want to disable it.